# Python conditional joining of *consecutive* strings that don't end in punctuation with those that do

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of words,

```
list1 = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you?', 'i', 'am', 'fine', 'thanks.', 'great!']
```

Which I would like to join to be,

```
list2 = ['hello how are you?', 'i am fine thanks.', 'great!']
```

Is there an simple pythonic way to do this? I have considered doing an itertools.groupby join but the problem is that all of the elements of my group don't have the same criteria (I can't just query if they all have punctuation). Basically, whether or not element x gets included is a function of potentially element x+n where n can be large. This complicates the problem.

Comment: FWIW I was looking for a Python solution

Comment: @NaruS: that question has zero bearing on this one. Not only is that a different programming language, it doesn't address producing groups whenever a condition in the list occurs. This question is not looking for a recursive join. If it was, I'm sure we could find be better duplicates that actually were using Python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `groupby()`; you'd get separate groups for those words with and without punctuation, which you then have to re-combine.

Use a generator function:

```
import string

def sentence_groups(l, punctuation=tuple(string.punctuation)):
    group = []
    for w in l:
        group.append(w)
        if w.endswith(punctuation):
            yield group
            group = []
    if group:
        yield group
```

The generator collects words from the input list until one ends with punctuation, at which point that whole group is yielded, after which the group is cleared for a new group.

When iteration ends and there are still words in the group, that last group is yielded too (even though they don't have punctuation at the end).

Use this together whith `str.join()` to produce your output:

```
>>> list1 = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you?', 'i', 'am', 'fine', 'thanks.', 'great!']
>>> [' '.join(group) for group in sentence_groups(list1)]
['hello how are you?', 'i am fine thanks.', 'great!']
```

I used *all* punctuation in the [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation) string; this is quite broad:

```
>>> string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

Pass in a tuple of specific punctuation characters as the second argument if you wanted to narrow that down, or hardcode your own definition.

Comment: That did it! Thanks Martjin!

Comment: Not really true what you say about `groupby`... with an appropriate key, you *don't* get separate groups you need to combine: https://eval.in/957101

Comment: Haha that's a lot work to cram it into the key. Something like that might be useful if you absolutely *needed* to use groupby I guess :)

Comment: @StefanPochmann: do I really need to add *or using convoluted key functions* to my answer? Like I commented on Ajax's answer: *Sure, you can make it work if you try hard enough, but this is practically unreadable*.

Answer (score 2):

A humble solution:

```
import string

words = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you?', 'i', 'am', 'fine', 'thanks.', 'great!']
sents = []

range_flag = 0
for index, word in enumerate(words):
  if word[-1] in string.punctuation:
    sents.append(words[range_flag+1:index+1])
    print(range_flag, index)
    range_flag = index

print([" ".join(s) for s in sents])

(0, 3)
(3, 7)
(7, 8)
['how are you?', 'i am fine thanks.', 'great!']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
import re
list1 = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you?', 'i', 'am', 'fine', 'thanks.', 'great!']
new_l = [list(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(list1, key=lambda x:bool(re.findall('(\?|\.)$', x)))]
final_data = [' '.join(new_l[i]+new_l[i+1]) if i+2 < len(new_l) else new_l[i][0] for i in range(0, len(new_l), 2)]
```

Output:

```
['hello how are you?', 'i am fine thanks.', 'great!']
```

Comment: Sure, you can make it work if you try hard enough, but **this is practically unreadable**. Good luck maintaining this code!